# I have a prob with sending mail with attachment using php

Tags: php, email

I have a problem with sending mail with attachment using php. The mail is sent with broken attachment, for example when I try to send `example.doc` with size `2 Mb`, in the mail I receive `noname` with size `1Kb` 
 
I use two files php.

The 1st one `mailClass.php` contain :

```
<?php 
class mail
{

function emailWithAttach($fromAdress,$toAdress,$mailSubject,$mailMessageHead,
                         $mailMessageMain,$mailMessageSign,$filePath,$fileName)
        {
            $fileatt_name = $fileName;
            $fileatt = $filePath.$fileName;
            $fileatt_type = "application/doc";
            $email_from = $fromaddress;
            $email_subject = $mailSubject;

            $email_message = $mailMessageHead. "<br>";
            $email_message .= $mailMessageMain. "<br>";
            $email_message .= $mailMessageSign;

            $email_to = $toAdress;
            $headers = "From: " .$email_from;

            $file = fopen ($fileatt."rb");
            $data = fread ($file, filesize($fileatt));
            fclose($file);

            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


            $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0 \n".
            "Content-Type : multipart/mixed:\n".
            "boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

            $email_message .=  "This is a multip-part message in MIME format. \n\n".
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n".
            "Content-Type : text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n".
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n".
            $email_message .= "\n\n"; 

            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

            $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n".
            "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type}:\n".
            "name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n".
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \n\n".
            $data .= "\n\n".
            "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

            if(@mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers))
            {
                return true;
            }  
        }
} 

?>
```

The second file `index.php` contain :

```
<?php
include "mailClass.php";

$testEmail = new mail;

$from = "sender@gmail.com";
$sendTo = "receiver@gmail.com";
$subject = "email with attachment";
$bodyHead = "welcome to the attachment email test";
$bodyMain = "hello iteb";
$bodyEnd = "Thank you";
$filePath = "";
$fileName = "example.doc";

if ($testEmail->emailWithAttach($from,$sendTo,$subject,$bodyHead,$bodyMain,$bodyEnd,$filePath,$fileName))
{
    echo "Email Send successful!!";
}   
else
{
    echo "Email Send Failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: I would recommend you check out swiftmailer for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your response I already used PHPMailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use phpmailer to send a mail: [Get it here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

It also has the advantage that you can send out many mails without opening and closing the connection each time as php's mail() function does.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried the PHPMailer and it worked for me. 
Another question, please how can I get the path of "browse file".
When I tried to get the path with JAVASCRIPT it gives me always "C:/fakepath/filename.extension" ... is there solution please ?

Comment: For more clearance, when I upload file via php, I want to get the filename (including the full path) on the client-side :)

Comment: You can't get the full path on client side as it would be a security issue if homepages could access local files. When uploaded in php you get the info in the $_FILES global variable. Try to do a print_r($_FILES); to see what you receive. The path you get here is a server path after an attachment has been uploaded. This path you can send to phpmailer to attach the file. You don't need the absolute path of the user.

Comment: You are very helpful :) 
I'm developing an application via AS3 which send  an attachment to mail but the prob now is; that I want to send a file without choosing the file with clicking on browse or something like that, just when I click send, the file will be automatically uploaded from a "path" and sent to the mail. is there a way to do that ? 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: No, as that would also be a security risk. The only way you could do this is to make the user accept and install a Java applet (not to be confused with Javascript). If you only use php and html you will have to ask the user to browse to the file and select it for upload and only then can you add it as an attachment